# Parse span class text with DOM PHP

Tags: php, parsing, dom

I've been having an issue trying to parse text in a span class with DOM. Here is my code example.

```
$remote = "http://website.com/";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($remote);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$node = $xpath->query('//span[@class="user"]');
echo $node;
```

and this returns the following error -> "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string". I am so lost I NEED HELP!!!

What I am trying to do is parse the user name between this span tag.

```
<span class="user">bballgod093</span>
```

Here is the full source from the remote website.

```
<div id="randomwinner">
    <div id="rndmLeftCont">
        <h2 id="rndmTitle">Hourly Random <span>Winner</span></h2>
    </div>
    <div id="rndmRightCont">
        <div id="rndmClaimImg">
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="200">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right" valign="middle">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <div id="rndmCaimTop">

    <span class="user">bballgod093</span>You've won 1000 SB</div>

    <div id="rndmCaimBottom">
        <a id="rndmCaimBtn" class="btn1 btn2" href="/?cmd=cp-claim-random" rel="nofollow">Claim Bucks</a>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This call

```
$node = $xpath->query('//span[@class="user"]');
```

does not return a string, but a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php).

You can use this list somewhat like array (using `$node->length` for the number of elements and `$node->item(0)` to get the first element) to get [`DOMNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) objects. Each of these objects has a `nodeValue` property which is a string.

So you would do something like

```
$node = $xpath->query('//span[@class="user"]');
if($node->length != 1) {
    // error?
}

echo $node->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Of course, changing the variable name for `$node` to something more appropriate would be nice.

Comment: @jennifer: Sorry, my mistake. I corrected the answer. Also, it does not make any difference how many instances you have. The interface to access the query results is the same no matter what.

Comment: thank you! i think its working but the page is blank when i reload but no text